# Vite clears the terminal when I run npm run dev

Tags: vite

I'm using `vite.config.js` to dynamically create some configurations. To debug it I use `console.log` to print some data.

However, when I run `npm run dev` vite runs the program very fast, and then clears the entire screen including my logs.

How can I prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use flag `--clearScreen false` when running the command.

Reference article [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#clearscreen)